# Why doesn't my thread return from a wait() after calling notifyAll() from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create two threads to act as counters. When one thread decrements its counter, it should toggle the value of the shared boolean flag field, call the notifyAll() method and release the other thread from the wait() method being called. The logic field serves as a means to avoid deadlock, i.e. one thread will call the wait() method when the flag field has a value of true, the other thread will call it when the flag field has a value of false. You can see the way I run the threads created from this class, as well as the expected output below. The problem is that both threads get stuck on the wait() method at the same time and only the first line of output goes through.

The expected output:

```
Thread No.1 4
Thread No.2 4
Thread No.1 3
Thread No.2 3
Thread No.1 2
Thread No.2 2
Thread No.1 1
Thread No.2 1
Thread No.1 0
Thread No.2 0
```

The actual output:

```
Thread No.2 4
```

The counter class:

```
public class CounterThread implements Runnable {
    private long counter;
    private static int threadNumber = 0;
    private int index = 0;
    private static boolean flag = true;
    private boolean logic;

    public CounterThread(long counter, boolean logic) {

        index = ++threadNumber;
        this.counter = counter;
        this.logic = logic;
    }

    private synchronized void toggleFlag() {
        flag = !flag;
        notifyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (counter > 0) {
            while (flag==logic) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            counter--;
            System.out.println("Thread No. " + index + " " +counter);
            toggleFlag();
        }
     }
 }
```

The way I run it:

```
public final class CounterThreadRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CounterThread counter1 = new CounterThread(5, true);
        CounterThread counter2 = new CounterThread(5, false);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(counter1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(counter2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "

Comment: some simplifications - toggle - `flag=!flag`,  wait - `while(flag==logic)`

Comment: @bayou.io thanks, I simplified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not notifying the thread that is waiting. You're only notifying the current thread, i.e. yourself. You need a shared object, perhaps a `static` in the class, that is used for both `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.

Comment: Minor nit-pick, but what you're really saying here is that each thread in the example has its own `CounterThread` instance, and they do not `notify()` each other's instance.  My point is, we don't notify _threads_, we notify _objects_ upon which other threads may be waiting.  The distiction is, when we say that we're doing something to a thread (e.g., interrupting a thread), it implies that we know which thread we are doing it to.  But the caller of `o.notify()` often does not know or care which thread (if any) will wake up.